# animate a view after drag

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-animation, objectanimator

This is the scenario: after that user select and drag view and released that view I want to dragged view goes back to where it was before.

```
mDragHelper = ViewDragHelper.create(this, 1.0f, new ViewDragHelper.Callback() {
        float startX, startY,startTX,startTY;

        @Override
        public boolean tryCaptureView(View child, int pointerId) {
            boolean res = mDragViews.contains(child);
            Log.d(TAG, "tryCaptureView() called with:res=" + res + " child = [" + child + "], pointerId = [" + pointerId + "]");
            return res;
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewPositionChanged(View changedView, int left, int top, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onViewPositionChanged(changedView, left, top, dx, dy);
        }

        @Override
        public int clampViewPositionHorizontal(View child, int left, int dx) {
            return left;
        }

        @Override
        public int clampViewPositionVertical(View child, int top, int dy) {
            return top;
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCaptured(View capturedChild, int activePointerId) {
            super.onViewCaptured(capturedChild, activePointerId);
            if (startX == 0) {
                startX = capturedChild.getX();
                startY = capturedChild.getY();
                startTX=capturedChild.getTranslationX();
                startTY=capturedChild.getTranslationY();
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "onViewCaptured: startX=" + startX + " startY=" + startY);
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewReleased(View releasedChild, float xvel, float yvel) {
            super.onViewReleased(releasedChild, xvel, yvel);
            releaseAnim(releasedChild, startX, startY,startTX,startTY);
        }
    });       

    private void releaseAnim(final View releasedChild, final float startX, final float startY, final float startTX, final float startTY) {
    Log.d(TAG, "releaseAnim() called with: releasedChild = [" + releasedChild + "], startX = [" + startTX + "], startY = [" + startTY + "]");
    PropertyValuesHolder pvhX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.X, releasedChild.getX(),startX);
    PropertyValuesHolder pvhY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.Y, releasedChild.getY(),startY);
    PropertyValuesHolder pvhTX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.TRANSLATION_X, releasedChild.getTranslationX(),startTX);
    PropertyValuesHolder pvhTY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.TRANSLATION_Y, releasedChild.getTranslationY(),startTY);
    ObjectAnimator downAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(
            releasedChild
            , pvhTX, pvhTY
            , pvhX, pvhY
    );

    downAnim.setInterpolator(sAccelerator);
    downAnim.setDuration(200);
    downAnim.start();


}
```

and it works but the problem is after the animation is done if I call to requestLayout my view get translation and position reverse of the dragged transition and position.
the result is the view not sit on where that was before.